# How ajax working on wame server?

Tags: ajax

Hi all I am first time starting to learn ajax from website w3schools, and I follow the step by step I'm trying to get an AJAX example working but i'm unable to get it working. could you help me please ? thanks you.

And here is my code

ajax.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add some `console.log`s then open the developer tools (normaly F12), so you can see whats going on.

Comment: how to add console.log s in ajax :D

Comment: you could write `console.log('loadDoc called');` before `var xhttp`. and before your `if`  write `console.log(xhttp.readyState, xhttp.status);`

Comment: Ok thanks you bro I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax like this,

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
$.ajax({
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                //progress

                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
                    //progress value e
                    load_progress(e);
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            },
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_info.txt",
            success: function(msg) {
               //when success //200 ok
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = msg;
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               //when error   
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is in `ajax_info.txt` file ??

Comment: I am try this exmaple from w3schools

Comment: clikc button try it ur selt

Comment: you need to create `ajax_info.txt` file, and put this text, `<p>AJAX is not a new programming language.</p>
<p>AJAX is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages.</p>` and save it on your file root

Comment: my file ajax in E:\wamp\www and i am create ajax_info.txt with text Hello world in E:\wamp\www  but its still not working :(

Comment: Thanks you bro , now its work for me , very thanks :)