# Passing Variable Value from PHP to Ajax and Changing Attribute Value in HTML

Tags: php, ajax

My PHP is returning this data to Ajax...

```
echo $data6['favorite_properties_id'];
```

I am updating it in one function and trying to send it to another using following html and jquery .

```
<a href="#"><img class="<?php if($favorite == 1){ echo 'alreadyfavorite';} else { echo 'addtofavorite';} ?>" pid="<?php echo $propertyid; ?>" fpid="<?php while($data5=$select5->fetch()){echo $data5['favorite_properties_id'];} ?>" src="../images/system/addtofavorite.png"></a>
```

This is my jquery...

```
    $('.alreadyfavorite1').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var del_id = $(this).attr('fpid');
        var $ele = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        var reference = this;

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../controllers/favoritesaddremove.php',
            data: 

            {
                del_id: del_id
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
            $ele.fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).remove(1000);
            }

        });
    });


// On Search Property Results Page - Add to Favorite Button (Heart)

    $('.addtofavorite').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var ins_id = $(this).attr('pid');
        var del_id = $(this).attr('fpid');
        var reference = this;
        /* alert(del_id);
        alert(ins_id); */

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../controllers/favoritesaddremove.php',
            data: 

            {
                ins_id: ins_id
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                $(reference).toggleClass("addtofavorite alreadyfavorite");
                $('.alreadyfavorite').attr('fpid', data);

            }
        });
    });
```

The second function is not working, but if i refresh the page then the second function is working...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870807/how-ajax-working-on-wame-server/35871124#35871124

Comment: document.getElementById("fpid").innerHTML = data; is not working

Answer (score 0):

First assign `some id` to the image and change `fpid` to `data-fpid`(data-attribute):

```
<a href="#"><img class="asdasd" id="aid" data-fpid="something"></a>
```

In your success try:

```
success: function(data)
            {
                $('#aid').data('fpid', data); //this should update the value in data-fpid
           }
```

Comment: $('.alreadyfavorite').attr('fpid', data);  this seems to be working but further data is not getting passed to ajax from the form as per below <a href="#"><img class="<?php if($favorite == 1){ echo 'alreadyfavorite';} else { echo 'addtofavorite';} ?>" pid="<?php echo $propertyid; ?>" fpid="<?php while($data5=$select5->fetch()){echo $data5['favorite_properties_id'];} ?>" src="../images/system/addtofavorite.png"></a>

Comment: into this function $('.alreadyfavorite').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var del_id = $(this).attr('fpid');
  var ins_id = $(this).attr('pid');

Comment: @DragonFire  how you are passing the data.log these value in console and see what they prints. using `console.log(ins_id )`

Comment: @DragonFire  if in your alert you are getting the values send them in ajax.post your ajax code in question.

Comment: please see edit i have pasted all code, this is a favorite / unfavorite toggle

Comment: @DragonFire do `echo $_POST['del_id']`  in  `favoritesaddremove.php` and see what it prints.in console also you can see what is the value going.